# when a linear application is a isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that if the matrix of a linear application is invertible then the application is a isomorphism.

Let $LH:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2 $ be a linear application
the associated matrix is $H$
and $x$ is a vector
Then
$LH(x)=Hx=y$
where $y$ is another vector
$H$ is invertible, so exists the matrix $ H^{-1}$
so
$$H^{−1}Hx=H^{-1}y$$
$$x=H^{−1}y$$
So the inverse application can be defined as
$L(H^{−1})(y)=H^{−1}y=x $

I would like to know if it is right

Comment: Notice that you can do your exponents by wrapping them in an {} , instead of in a parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a vector spaces $V,W$, an isomorphism consists of an invertible linear map , i.e., a linear map with a linear inverse. Matrices represent linear maps, so that you have the necessary ingredients for an isomorphism between vector spaces (in this case from $\mathbb R^2$ to itself ) a linear map given by $H$, and its inverse matrix (which exists by assumption) $H^{-1}$